# The SDK 'Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found in VSCode with ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Getting the following error in VSCode when trying to run a ASP.Net Core project on Windows:

```
The SDK 'Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found
```

My `csproj` starts with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` and somehow it is not able to resolve this SDK.

Answer (score -1):

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` in a `csproj` file is basically telling VSCode to run this project in IIS.

Installing IIS feature in Windows solved it for me.

Comment: the `Project  Sdk` attribute has nothing to do with the hosting method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2017